# Can't do a GET request using email as the primary key - "detail": "Not found."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to do a GET request on an API that returns the relevant entry but keep getting `not found`.
If I call:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/bookings/booking/`

I can GET all the entries but when I try GETing one entry based on the primary key (which is an email address (nested object) - yes I have considered changing this as I've read it's bad practice for many reasons). It just returns detail not found. Other endpoints where the primary key is ID work just fine.

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/bookings/booking/2customer%40business2.com/`

Can someone explain to me why the email doesn't return an entry.`

but I keep getting:

`"detail": "Not found."`

models.py

```py
class CustomerBookings(models.Model):
    
    completed = models.BooleanField()

    booking_startdate_time = models.DateTimeField()

    dynamic_slot = models.ForeignKey(DynamicSlot, blank=True, null= True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, related_name="%(class)s_dynamicslot")
    
    customer = models.OneToOneField(Customer, primary_key=True, blank=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="%(class)s_customer")
```

views.py

```py
class BookingAPIViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # permission_classes= [DjangoModelPermissions] - disabled for testing
    serializer_class = CustomerBookingsSerializer
    queryset = CustomerBookings.objects.all()
```

serializer.py

```py
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerBookings
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Comment: what will be the output if we call `Customer.objects.get(pk="2customer%40business2.com")`?

Comment: When I try `Customer.objects.get(pk="2customer%40business2.com")` in the shell it returns `Customer matching query does not exist` but `Customer.objects.get(pk="2customer@business2.com")` returns the correct object

when I try `127.0.0.1/users/customer/pk=2customer%40business2.com` OR `127.0.0.1/users/customer/pk=2customer@business2.com` it returns `{"detail":"Not found."}`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 warnings here:

1. Your search phrase is [URL Encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP), you can see something like `%40` in the phrase.

```py
import urllib

urllib.parse.unquote("2customer%40business2.com")
```

2. Your ModelViewSet wants `id` of the Booking model here in the path, like: `/booking/1123/`. You need to override the `.retrieve()` method of the class `BookingAPIViewSet` and make it possible to search by another field, like email. [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset). Stop breakpoint at the beginning of the method and take a look at what args and kwargs it takes.

Comment: Thanks for this I don't quite understand where you find the the first warning; I get the URL encoded. I just tried the string through the call for sanity reasons. 
Thanks for the .retrieve() route it makes sense to me now. Also I should really be using email as a PK in the first place. I'll up vote your answer. Much appreciated 8^)

Comment: Maybe I've used the wrong term "warning", I think it should sound like "ways to improve". No warnings in console or staff like that of course. Yep, if you are using decoded from URL encoding - that's what you need. 

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the of output of the query with:

```
Model.object.get(pk='2customer%40business2.com')
```

Or use:

```
Model.object.all().get(pk='2customer%40business2.com')
```

You can also use `get_object_or_404` to test by importing it like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
```

With that, you will be able to trace it. But based on the error message that you are getting, it shows the data you are trying to get from the database doesn't exist, hence you are getting a "Not found" error.

It is the same thing as using `get_object_or_404`. It will return a 404 (Not found) if the data is not in your database.

Comment: The object does exist when I look for it using ORM I can find it with `...get(pk="2customer@business2.com")` but when I try the endpoint `127.0.0.1/users/customer/pk=2customer@business2.com` OR `....pk=2customer%40business2.com` I get `{"detail":"Not found."}`